# Why Chrome 64-bit is installed in 32-bit Program Files?

Tags: google-chrome, 64-bit

I have Chrome 64-bit. I could not update it to 64-bit, so I full desinstalled 32-bit version and installed 64-bit version.

I´m pretty sure that I have 64-bit version:

```
Versão 37.0.2062.120 m (64-bit)

Google Chrome   37.0.2062.120 (Versão oficial 281580) m
SO  Windows 
Blink   537.36 (@181352)
JavaScript  V8 3.27.34.17
Flash   15.0.0.152
Agente do usuário   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
```

But the exe file is installed on C:\Program Files (x86)

```
Linha de comando    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Caminho do executável   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 64 bit &32 bit google chrome, the installation location is C:/Program files(x86) and if you need more verification you can open the task manager and check the following

chrome.exe    - shown only for  64bit-Chrome

Chrome.exe*32 - shown only for 32 bit chrome

Answer (score 10):

The answer is [on the Chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=380177) (see comments #18 and #26).

In short, the dev team decided to keep things that way because it simplifies the upgrade process when migrating from 32-bits Chrome to 64-bits Chrome. They have not changed it yet because it has no user impact.

Comment: But why is it installed in C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application on Windows Server 2016?

Comment: @Toolkit, the default has been changed for new installations https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiNvPfl2Jn1AhWxumMGHY4FCuAQFnoECAkQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ghacks.net%2F2020%2F06%2F11%2Fgoogle-chrome-is-soon-going-to-be-installed-in-a-different-directory-on-windows%2F&usg=AOvVaw0zoF82Qnvhr9OUMD1P9T3t

Answer (score 6):

Because this simplified the upgrade path from 32-bit to 64-bit. When Chrome auto-updated you to 64-bit, the installer need not use multiple program files directories.

Comment: That's not good at all. If you want to make clean Chrome installation, this may cause problems.